# Simulations using alternative initial conditions

Tags: programming, manipulate

With help from some of you guys here in this forum, I have developed the following code, which works perfectly. My questions are:

1. how to automate the simulations with varying initial conditions. In the following CODE, a given set of initial conditions {1.5, Null, Null, 2, 10, 8, Null} is used to solve the model. This is just one set of initial conditions. I like to iterate the model with alternative sets.
2. how to iterate the model with 2nd order difference system. One can just revise one of the equations in the model to have a 2nd order difference model. Any equation in the model can be written as a 2nd order difference equation for illustrative purposes.

The following CODE works fine in my computer

```
(* First-Difference Model - Simulations for a given set of initial conditions *)

Clear[T];
T = 10;
Manipulate[
  model = Rest[
    NestList[{{A, R, K, II, Y, CC, U} = #;
      A = (1 + z) A,
      R = a A CC,
      K = Sqrt[b] a A CC,
      II = (1 + m) II,
      Y = (1 + n) Y,
      CC = d (Y - ((1 - a) K + II)),
      U = e Log[CC]} &, {1.5, Null, Null, 2, 10, 8, Null}, T]  
 (*I like to iterate for alternative initial conditions *)];
  Grid[{{
    ListLinePlot[{model[[All,1]], model[[All,7]]},
      AxesLabel -> {t,"technology vs utility\n Subscript[A, t],Subscript[U, t]"},
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotLegends->{"Subscript[A, t]","Subscript[U, t]"}],
    ListLinePlot[{model[[All,4]],model[[All,7]]},
      AxesLabel -> 
        {t,"investment vs utility\n 
            Subscript[I, \[InvisibleComma]t], Subscript[U, \[InvisibleComma]t]"},
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotLegends -> 
       {"Subscript[I, \[InvisibleComma]t]","Subscript[U, \[InvisibleComma]t]"}]}
    }],
  Style["Model Simulations", Bold, Medium], 
  Delimiter,
  {{z, 0.3}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{a, 0.2}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, 3}, 0, 5,  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{d, 0.6}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{m, 0.2}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{n, 0.4}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{e, 0.95}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: simulation]

Comment: You tagged this with wolfram-programming-cloud. The tag does not seem relevant to your question.

Comment: For the initial conditions you could use a do loop that references a vector of different initial conditions, themselves generated by using Table[]. However, I'm sure there is a better way to loop in Mathematica than using a Do loop (i.e. nest or something). For the second question actually giving some background on the problem you're modeling would be useful (i.e. equations). It's not clear what you are trying to solve with a "2nd order difference system"

Comment: You say "The following CODE works fine in my computer". It doesn't produce any useful or even visible output on mine. Perhaps, `... alternative initial conditions *)];` should be changed to `... alternative initial conditions *)],`. That is, I think the semi-colon that follows the comment and the right-bracket should be a comma.

Comment: I added ListLinePlots to the CODE. Now it should work.

Comment: Dear skywalker, I have a larger model to run, but I try to get results with a sample. I just like to learn how to run the model with a 2nd difference equation in it.

Comment: The segment of code beginning `!(TraditionalForm` appears to be output.  Please replace it by code in `InputForm`.  Then, others will be able to run your code and offer useful advice.

Comment: I simply do not know how to copy the CODE in input format. I copy and past the CODE, but the I get all the backslah and other signs. How can I the CODE properly?